# Uploading video to azure without saving it first

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I have an mvc site which takes a post with a video file which is uploaded to azure media server. 
However to use the azure sdk I need to save the video first to get a string file path . File.SaveAs(). Is there any way to avoid the need to save the file. So the post just take the file and upload it directly azure with the sdk

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample from Microsoft showing how to upload a file stream to Media Services at https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-upload-a-stream-to-d2750102.  I'd think you'd just need to grab the incoming stream from the post and push it up.